# Rails 5: Best way to iterate through a polymorphic model and find the top level parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Edit: In an effort to remain as transparent as possible and provide a working solution to people in the future I wanted to explain how I used @John Hayes-Reed's answer with my issue. I'll update the methods and models below.

Updated method:

```
#User.rb
def self.find_all_user_comments(user)
  @comment_hash = []
  @user_comments = Comment.where(user_id: user.id)
  @user_comments.all.each do |co|
     post = co.find_parent_post
    @comment_hash.push( { comment: co, post: post} )
  end
  @comment_hash
end
```

New method I got from the answer below:

```
#comment.rb
def find_parent_post
  return self.commentable if self.commentable.is_a?(Post)
  self.commentable.find_parent_post
end
```

My controller where I call the method:

```
#users_controller.rb
def control_panel
  @comments = User.find_all_user_comments(current_user)
end
```

### End edit

I'm trying to implement a "most recent comments" for a user in their control panel. A comment can be left on a `Post` or another `comment`.

In my view I want to display the `:body` of the `comment` along with the `post` it was created in via a hash. That goes for a `comment`s `comment` as well. Luckily, Comment's can only go two deep like so

```
Post
  Comment
    Child Comment # Would like to find the parent post.
    Child Comment
  Comment
```

I had a method, which I will input below, which worked well for `comment`s that were left on a post, but would break when trying to find a `comment` had a `commentable_type: "Comment"`.

My only solution would be to have an `if` statement that said `if commentable_type == "Comment"`, find *that* Comments parent, grab the Post, then take the Post` and bring it back down to that child comment and push it into the hash that way.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way (either AR or SQL) to do such a thing so that in the end, I can find the `comment`'s parent `Post` is in even if it's a `comment` of a `comment`.

Here is all the information that I think will help:

Schema:

```
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "body"
  t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  t.integer  "commentable_id"
  t.string   "commentable_type"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end

create_table "forums", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "description"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_forums_on_user_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "description"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "forum_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.index ["forum_id"], name: "index_posts_on_forum_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id", using: :btree
end

...User table omitted for brevity...
```

Models:

```
#post model
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :forum

has_many :comments, as: :commentable

#comment model
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
has_many :comments, as: :commentable
```

Method as it stands now. Wont work when it finds a comment with `commentable_type: "Comment"`:

```
  def self.find_all_user_comments(user)
    @comment_hash = []
    @user_comments = Comment.where(user_id: user.id)
    @user_comments.all.each do |co|
      post = Post.find(co.commentable_id)
      @comment_hash.push( { comment: co, post: post} )
    end
    @comment_hash
  end
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<h3>Recent comments:</h3>
  <% if @comments.any? %>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>Post</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @comments.each do |co| %>
        <tr class="comment-<%= co[:comment].id %>">
          <td><%= truncate(co[:comment].body, length: 50) %></td>
          <td><%= truncate(co[:post].title, length: 50) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to "destroy", comment_path(co[:comment]), remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?"} %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a method to your comment class, and use a bit of recursion to get the job done (well not technically true recursion as it calls the method on a second instance, but we can use a similar concept), something along the lines of:

```
def find_parent_post
    return self.commentable if self.commentable.is_a?(Post)
    self.commentable.find_parent_post
end
```

This will also be future proof for if you ever want to nest your comments even deeper.

Comment: this is a nicer solution to mine - it keeps the logic contained within the model where it belongs - but i just love ternary operators XD

Comment: @John Hayes-Reed. I like your future-proof solution. How would I best go about implementing it in the model I have?

Comment: Never mind. I was was able to make it work@John Hayes-Reed, thank you!

Comment: @Antonio Im not currently in a position where I can test it out, but I think if you add the above method into your comment model, and then in your self.find_all_user_comments method change `post = Post.find(co.commentable_id)` to `post = co.find_parent_post` it should be ready to go? or something along those lines!

Comment: great! this way we can: `@commentable.find_parent_post if @commentable.is_a?(Comment)` & `@commentable unless @commentable.is_a?(Comment)`

Answer (score 1):

Well a possible one liner that would find the post could be:

```
post = (comment.commentable.is_a? Post) ? comment.commentable : comment.commentable.commentable
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, I like the idea and I don't use ternary as much as I should. I ended up going for the other solution, but I appreciate the help!